# Access public variable defined inside method of a class php

Tags: php, class, oop

I am new to php and what I am trying to do is get $conn variable outside of the class. 
I included this file from another file and tried to get the variable using `$dbConfig->conn` but it returns nothing.

This is the notice I got on the another page. 
Notice: Undefined variable: dbConfig in C:\xampp\htdocs\Chat\login.php on line 8

```
<?php 
class dbConfig {
public $host;
public $username;
public $password;
public $dab;
public $conn;

public function dbConnect() {
$conn = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->username,$this->password);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else{
    echo "Connected successfully to server";
}

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($conn, $this->dab);

if (!$db_selected) {
    // if the given database doesn't exists
    // creates new database with that name
    $db_sql = 'CREATE DATABASE chatapp';

    // verify the database is created
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $db_sql)){
        echo "Database chatapp already exists or created successfully\n";
    } else {
        echo 'Error creating database: ' . mysqli_error() . "\n";
    }
}

// creating tables
$table_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (".
        "uid INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,".
        "username VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE,".
        "password VARCHAR(50),".
        "name VARCHAR(100),".
        "email VARCHAR(70) UNIQUE); ";

// verify the table is created
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $table_sql)) {
        echo "Table: users already exists or created successfully\n";
    } else {
        echo 'Error creating table: ' . mysqli_error($table_sql) . "\n";
    }
}
}

$obj = new dbConfig();

$obj->host = 'localhost';
$obj->username = 'root';
$obj->password = '';
$obj->dab = 'chatapp';
$obj->dbConnect();
```

Comment: There is no `$dbConfig`, there is `$obj`

Comment: The warning you note has nothing to do with the code shown.Where are you trying to reference `$dbCOnfig`?

Comment: As a side note, you probably DON'T want all that logic about creating databases and table inside a class that is largely intended to give you a database connection. You should handle that logic elsewhere - like in an application set-up script.

Comment: That returned null value.

Comment: @MikeBrant I included this file from another file and tried to get $conn variable which resulted in the notice given above.

Comment: @RajeebTheGreat Yes, but your message says `$dbCOnfig` is not defined, not that a property `$dbzZConfig->conn` is not publicly accessbile.  First, solve the problem of why `$dbConfig` is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how you're referencing the class variable inside your methods.  Look:

```
public function dbConnect() {
    $conn = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->username,$this->password);
    ...
```

Here you're creating a local variable (scope restricted to the current method, only) called `$conn`.  Because you're working with an instance of the class, you need to access your class members using `$this`:

```
$this->conn = mysqli_connect(...);
```

Take a look at [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) for further info.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have instantiated `$obj` not `$dbConfig` so use `$obj`
2. In the class you need to assign `$conn` as an object property

---

```
$this->conn = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->username,$this->password);
```

And then use `$this->conn` inside the class.